# JavaScript Animations: value of changed property after animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, slider, dom-events, slide

I have some JavaScript code which slides the div from left to right by changing its 'left' CSS property when mouse is clicked on div. The code is working perfectly fine.
Initially, div's `left = 0`.
Suppose I want to slide the div to some random number. I will do it like this:

```
function move(){
  var final = Math.random()*100  //Lets suppose final gets the value equal to 145 in this case
  
  ....code for sliding goes here

}
```

So, now the div's left should be equal 145px now.

Now, when I click on the div again, this would happen:

```
function move(){
 var final = Math.random()*100  //Lets suppose final gets the value equal to 30 in this case
  
  ....code for sliding goes here

}
```

Now, shouldn't the div slide from 145px to 30 px? because when I clicked on the div for the first time its left became 145 px and no longer remains 0. In my case what happens is when I click on the again, first it goes back to 0 px and then moves 30px.

Comment: What is your animation code?

Comment: @Kolink The animation code  is too long!! I am using easing effects too in JAVAscript.. Its too lengthy to post here

Comment: how does Math.random()*100 get you 145 ?

Comment: @Nanz, that was just some random number from my side too :p

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would be a LOT easier with a transition:

CSS:

```
.moving_element {transition:all 0.4s ease; -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;}
```

(Replace that class as needed for your code)

JS:

```
elem.style.left = Math.random()*100+"px";
```

That's all you need. The browser will smoothly move the element from one position to the next in the defined time.

Comment: I want to do it with Javascript, Not CSS please. I already know CSS transitions are lor more easier. But learning JavaScript at present :)

Comment: Oh, I see. *La souris est en-dessous de la table. Le chat est sur la chaise. Et le singe est sur la branche.*